# ¿Como manejar los roles en mysql para ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: java, stored-procedure, users-roles

En mysql workbench tengo un procedimiento, cree un rol llamado clientes_rol y le asigne el privilegio para ejecutar el procedimiento, posteriormente ese rol se lo asigne a un usuario que es cliente para que lo pudiera ejecutar. Me conecto como ese usuario en workbench y lo ejecuto sin problemas, pero al momento de ejecutarlo desde java no puedo, me dice que no existe tal procedimiento, ya cheque el nombre, los parametros y todo.
Me di cuenta que si le asigno el privilegio para ejecutarlo individualmente (sin el rol) si lo ejecuta, que puedo hacer para ejecutarlo usando el rol, ya que son varios procedimientos y quiero usar el rol y solo asignarlo a cada usuario.

Comment: Revisa si `SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='TU_USUARIO'` te regresa mas de un registro.

Comment: Solo me arroja un registro

Comment: Sugiero que agregues a tu pregunta la versión de Connector/J y la salida desde Java de `SHOW GRANTS`.